# can i delete old .PyCharm folders in my user directory

Tags: pycharm

While using pycharm and updating regularly i notice some ".PyCharm*" folders piling up in my my windows user directory, obviously one for every installed version.

I guess i only need the one of the recent version and can delete the older ones without problems?

thanks

Chris

Answer (score 6):

**.pycharmxx** directory saves the **IDE settings** of the particular version of the IDE. So, yes it is safe to delete the older ones. A [similar question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000020884-delete-folder-with-a-old-version-) has been answered in the jetbrains support forum.